# How can I ignore all cite commands?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I would like to compile a latex file without the references section. If I simply remove the `\bibliography` command, it leaves a lot of `[?]`s in my document where I have `\cite` Is there a way I can compile while ignoring all the `\cite`s? The output should be a document without any citations and references.

Comment: I don't think there is an official interface for that. The code will depend on the bibliography/citation packages you load. With the standard LaTeX definition of `\cite` you could try `\makeatletter\def\@citex[#1]#2{}\makeatother` or `\makeatletter\def\@citex[#1]#2{\unskip}\makeatother` (the latter if you want to get rid of the space before `\cite` as well). The solution will have to be different for `natbib`.

Comment: `\renewcommand\cite[2][]{}` will make them go but output from `... as described in  \cite{wibble} the ...`  will be a bit weird.